# Who are the "villains from Star Trek" that Sofie Fatale is dressed like?

Tags: star-trek, character-identification

In [*Kill Bill*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0266697/), O-Ren Ishii's right hand Sofie Fatale:

[image: Sofie Fatale]

is described by *The Bride* as

> The pretty lady who's **dressed like she's a villain on Star Trek** is O-Ren's best friend and her lawyer, Sofie Fatale.

<sup>Thanks to [tugs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/8927/tugs) for the exact quote. Emphasis mine.</sup>

I've been scratching my head since the first time I saw the film who could be meant by that. The closest uniform her clothes resemble would actually be TNG-style Starfleet uniforms without the colour (past Season 3). Considering the [sequel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0378194/)'s [take on superheroes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/23432/2565) could it possibly be that The Bride perceived the Federation to be the villains in Star Trek? Otherwise who is meant by this comparison?

Could it possibly have been a mix-up with a different Franchise/Universe?

Comment: She looks more like the bad guys from Superman II.

Comment: My guess would be the TNG era Romulans, but it's just based on her high forehead, and her "exotic" skin tone (it's not really all that exotic but in comparison to both Uma Thurman and David Carradine's pale skin it is)

Comment: @Monty129: Romulans would've been my second guess, but since the connection strikes me as so week I didn't want to bias potential answers by including that in the OP.

Comment: @bitmask I agree it is a very thin line of reasoning.  I think ultimately it was Tarantino trying to be clever in his dialogue as usual.

Comment: For some reason her face reminds me a lot of [Gul Dukat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dukat_%28Star_Trek%29), except without all the plated ridges.

Comment: @Tacroy: Yeah, could be brother and sister ... No, really, What?!

Comment: @bitmask Well that's why I said "for some reason" - I read "Star Trek", saw her face, and thought "huh she looks like that guy". I don't know why, she just reminds me of him.

Comment: I'm going to guess this was a mistake on their part.  [The part of the outfit in the screenshot looks similar to what Peacekeeper grunts wear](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/1ebNxQ5vgGo/0.jpg).  And she looks like [Aeryn Sun](http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070107210539/farscape/images/d/d1/Aeryn_001.jpg), former Peacekeeper grunt.

Comment: @Izkata: Yes, they look similar. What Universe/Franchise is that?

Comment: @bitmask [Farscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farscape)

Comment: @Izkata: I upgraded the question to include story identification. Why don't you make your case in an answer?

Comment: Quickly checked Kill Bill's script.  The line seems to be: "The pretty lady who's dressed like she's a villain on Star Trek is O-Ren's best friend and her lawyer, Sofie Fatale."  I'd say that rules out facial resemblance answers.

Comment: @tugs: Thanks, I really should have checked that myself. I'll change the quote.

Comment: Well, thanks to this question, a Google image search for "star trek villains" now [includes](https://www.google.com/search?q=star+trek+villains&hl=en&tbm=isch) poor Sofie :) You'll need to scroll down a bit.

Comment: Sometimes jokes aren't literal. This is the case, here.

Answer (score 8):

The outfit and hair style look similar to a notable *Star Trek* villain:
[image: Screenshot of Khan from Star Trek: TOS]

Khan Noonien Singh in his first appearance in the *Star Trek: TOS* episode *Space Seed*.

Answer (score 5):

I have the feeling this was a mistake on the part of the writers.  Intentional or not, I don't know.

From [Farscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farscape), this is Aeryn Sun, former Peacekeeper, next to the image from the question:

[image: Aeryn Sun and Sofie Fatale]

Not only do their faces look very similar, there's a handful of other reasons:

- Star Trek has no consistent "bad guys" - temporary alliances have even been made with the Borg and Species 8472, and they only comprise a handful of episodes in any series.

  - Except perhaps the Dominion, but only in DS9 and the Founders look nothing like the person in question.
- The Peacekeepers from Farscape were "bad guys" from Episode 1 all the way through the series-ending movies, *The Peacekeeper Wars*.
- Part of the Peacekeeper uniform involves keeping long hair out of the way - tightly tied back, same as Sofie Fatale appears to have.
- Likewise, Peacekeepers always wear black.  Usually with body armor, but not always.

This is Captain Crais, another Peacekeeper and the primary antagonist for the first season, to compare the outfit and hairstyle.  He wears a tightly-wound ponytail:

[image: Captain Crais]

Unfortunately, Farscape is not well-known.  If it was mentioned in the movie, not many would understand the reference.  However, Star Trek - even if only by name - is known by just about everyone, and the layman often has difficulties distinguishing one space opera from another.

**EDIT:** A better shot of the Peacekeeper uniforms.  This is Lieutenant Teeg, a bridge officer on Crais's ship, from the very first episode:

[image: Teeg and Crais]

Comment: I considered Aeryn Sun but the reference to Star Trek derailed my decision. I agree, the physical resemblance is striking.

Comment: I would really be disappointed if Tarantino had made such a blunder. Anyway, I'm going to let the community decide which answer is right (by votes).

Comment: @bitmask - Ah, but it's not Tarantino (a fan of the genre) who makes the mistake. It's the Bride. We may be looking at a form of the unreliable narrator.

Comment: @SystemDown: Well, that excuse works for me. Tarantino back to god-like status.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Joanne Linville's Romulan Commander]

**I think Joanne Linville's Romulan Commander from the Star Trek TOS was the character she meant. Here is a picture of the Romulan commander from the TOS episode "[The Enterprise Incident.](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Enterprise_Incident_%28episode%29)"**

Comment: I don't know, they do have similar facial features, but other than that I see no similarity. More importantly, I distinctively remember the description being *plural*, so the facial features of one individual would be out of the picture, right?

Comment: I looked at a lot of the TOS Romulans and they all had a similar appearance. Do a google search for TOS Romulans. It was an aspect of the makeup which makes the appearance similar (in my opinion). But when I saw Sofie Fatale, I had no problem knowing who he was talking about. I also considered his age as a factor.

Comment: Please see update of the OP. The correct quote specifically refers to her clothing. This was my mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

She does have a noticeable [Widow's Peak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widow%27s_peak), which resembles the common pointed Romulan hairstyle, seen here:

[image: Romulan female]
[image: Another Romulan]
[image: Romulan male]

Answer (score 0):

I found another possibility, from Star Trek.  But technically, they're not villains, and were only in a small handful of episodes (4 ENT, 3 DS9): [Section 31](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Section_31)

[image: Three operatives from Section 31]

Comment: I think ENT is too new to have been referenced in Kill Bill.

Comment: @bitmask Hmm..  Almost certainly true.  First appearance in ENT was Season 4 (2004-2005), and I'm pretty sure they didn't use these uniforms.  However, that screenshot is from DS9, which aired several years before Kill Bill.